# Avro schema getting undefined type name when using Record type

Tags: avro, avsc

so im trying to parse an object with this avro schema.

object is like:

```
myInfo: {size: 'XL'}
```

But Its behaving like the record type doesn't actually exist and im getting a `undefined type name: data.platform_data.test_service.result.record at Function.Type.forSchema` for it.

schema looks like:

```
  "avro": {
    "metadata": {
      "loadType": "full",
      "version": "0.1"
    },
    "schema": {
      "name": "data.platform_data.test_service.result",
      "type": "record",
      "fields": [
        {
          "name": "myInfo",
          "type": "record",
          "fields": [{
            "name": "size",
            "type": {"name":"size", "type": "string"}
          }]
      }
      ]
    }
  }
```

I should mention im also using `avsc` for this. Anybody have any ideas? I've tried pretty much all combinations but afaik the only way of parsing out an objct like this is with `record`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Playing around with the schema, I found that `"type": "record"` is a problem. I moved it to nested definition. And it worked. Seems like description [here](https://avro.apache.org/docs/current/spec.html#schema_record) is little bit confusing.

Change
Before:

```
{
  "name": "myInfo",
  "type": "record",
  "fields": [{
    "name": "size",
    "type": {"name":"size", "type": "string"}
  }]
}
```

After:

```
{
  "name": "myInfo",
  "type": {
    "type": "record",
    "name": "myInfo",
    "fields": [
      {
        "name": "size",
        "type": {"name":"size", "type": "string"}
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Updated schema which is working:

```
{
  "name": "data.platform_data.test_service.result",
  "type": "record",
  "fields": [
    {
      "name": "myInfo",
      "type": {
        "type": "record",
        "name": "myInfo",
        "fields": [
          {
            "name": "size",
            "type": {"name":"size", "type": "string"}
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

To make a record attribute nullable, process is same as any other attribute. You need to union with `"null"` (as show in below schema):

```
{
  "name": "data.platform_data.test_service.result",
  "type": "record",
  "fields": [
    {
      "name": "myInfo",
      "type": [
        "null",
        {
          "type": "record",
          "name": "myInfo",
          "fields": [
            {
              "name": "size",
              "type": {
                "name": "size",
                "type": "string"
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: This works thank you so much! How would you make the `myInfo` field nullable in this case? I tried turning type into an array with the 1st being the current object and 2nd position being `null` but it didnt work.

Comment: @Strobe_, updated answer to included nullable record attribute.

Comment: I would upvote this 100x if I could. Couldn't find the answer anywhere.